# Which is the best for syncing app with server Syncadapter or Service?

Tags: android, service, android-syncadapter

Which is best way for syncing my app with service and look for any changes in server or vice versa.

Which is the best way to sync my app with server `syncadapter` or `service` if there is any change need to notify user using `notification manager`. And how can i do this ?

I cannot find any proper solution for `syncadatper` which is best `alaram manager` with `service` or `syncadapter`.

Please your valuable advise would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Both are there for a reason.. check [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219357/design-pattern-for-syncing-data-in-android) link of stackexchange for more details.